# Closure-compiler missing ECMASCRIPT6 option in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ecmascript-6, google-closure-compiler

I've installed closure-compiler in my Ubuntu machine.

I need to set `--language_in` to `ECMASCRIPT6`, but it says it doesn't exist:

```
Unknown language `ECMASCRIPT6' specified.
```

Running:

```
closure-compiler --language_in ECMASCRIPT5 myjsfile.js
```

Getting things like:

```
ERROR - Parse error. missing ; before statement
let comments =
```

*(Complainning about let)*

Is there a way of getting an updated version of closure-compiler that includes `ECMASCRIPT6' language?

Answer (score 0):

The flags were renamed. Try `--language_in ECMASCRIPT_2015`.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not a valid option neither. If I run `closure-compiler --help` it says the following for the language_in: `Sets what language spec that input
                                          sources conform. Options: ECMASCRIPT3
                                          (default), ECMASCRIPT5,
                                          ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT (default:
                                          ECMASCRIPT3)`

Comment: How are you running `closure-compiler`? The compiler is distributed as a jar (or JS for that version).

Comment: I was using this one: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/closure-compiler - I'm now using the google one, which is using Java, that one works well. But I would expect the one included in Ubuntu to be working with ES6 too

Comment: The Ubuntu version looks to be from Feb 2013. That is extremely old.

Comment: Filed a bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/closure-compiler/+bug/1792452

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to use a more recent version of the compiler.